# Automatic volume Calculations of sanitary sewer excavations using manhole 3d point data

Tags: qgis

I have a set of sanitary sewer manhole data in point format. The points consist of x,y,ground elevation and invert level elevation .

I would like to calculate the volume of excavation from one manhole to another using qgis.

As of now I'm using the manual method by finding the cross sectional area using 3d coordinates from manhole to manhole then multiplying it with the width of 1 meter. How can I automate this process?

Comment: These are existing manholes, or proposed? What about the trenches between manholes?

Comment: They are proposed . The volume I want to calculate is for the trenches.  From manhole to manhole